# Do any USA states require accepting US cash for payment of goods or services?

Tags: united-states, business, currency, payment, us-states

According to the United States Federal Reserve:

> There is no federal statute mandating that a private business, a person, or an organization must accept currency or coins as payment for goods or services. Private businesses are free to develop their own policies on whether to accept cash unless there is a state law that says otherwise.

Source: https://www.federalreserve.gov/faqs/currency_12772.htm

Are there any states, districts, regions, or territories within the USA that mandate that a private business, a person, or an organization must accept US currency or coins as payment for goods or services?

Comment: Related - https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/legal_tender#:~:text=Legal%20Tender%20refers%20to%20all,or%20services%20that%20were%20rendered.

Answer (score 3):

Not at the level of the state, but businesses subject to King County (WA) jurisdiction will, effective Jan. 1 2025, have to accept cash (within limits: not larger than $20 bill, not more that $200) for in-person transactions. Ad hoc exemptions are allowed in case of significant theft history, business operated at home, or with only one on-site employee.

Comment: Thanks.  Just curious... do you know the reasoning for the ad hoc exception for businesses with only one on-site employee?

Comment: The rationale was apparently dribbled out across a number of meetings, and nobody who monitors this stuff summarized their thinking, but I imagine it has to do with security and not having a person who can take the cash to the bank.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable guess.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In [massachusetts](/questions/tagged/massachusetts), the [General Law, chapter 255D, section 10A](https://malegislature.gov/Laws/GeneralLaws/PartIII/TitleIV/Chapter255D/Section10A) outlaws discrimination against cash buyers by retail (as opposed to wholesale) businesses. The section reads, in full:

> Section 10A. No retail establishment offering goods and services for sale shall discriminate against a cash buyer by requiring the use of credit by a buyer in order to purchase such goods and services. All such retail establishments must accept legal tender when offered as payment by the buyer.